# Remover vertical bar in wordpress login page

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to customize my wordpress login page, But I am having a problem on removing the vertical line before the option Forgot Password. Check this url http://www.thedesigncereal.com/wp-login.php I came up with the codes like this,

```
function remove_vertical_text($text)

{

    if($text == '|'){$text='';}
    return $text;

}

add_filter('gettext', 'remove_vertical_text');
```

But it is not working, any idea on this?

Comment: What is the content of '$text' before your 'if' statement ?

Comment: this is just a filter, it traces the wp-login.php if there are string like | existing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `wp-login.php` file and find this part, on line (about) 530

```
<p id="nav">
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php', 'login') ?>"><?php _e('Log in') ?></a> |
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login') ?>" title="<?php _e('Password Lost and Found') ?>"><?php _e('Lost your password?') ?></a>
</p>
```

or on line (about) 660

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login') ?>"><?php _e('Register') ?></a> |
```

and delete that character. There's no need for any hack :)

Comment: geez, sorry I'm new to wordpress. I hope I could learn more from u. :)

Comment: @user3627265 That's fine. We all lear ;) I love hacks as well, but sometimes you just don't need them; as in this case.

Comment: I would call this a "hack", since this change will be lost the next time you update WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$text = "| <a href=''>asdasdasdasd</a>";
 $str = str_replace('|', '', $text);
 echo $str;
```

Its just trim the | from the string.

Comment: this messed up the page. :(

Comment: do the trim inside <p id="nav"> right now u have 4 p tags 2 tags without ids and 2 like old. remove the new patches and do this inside the p tag have id nav